# Inserting new line in .html() using D3

Tags: text, d3.js, line-breaks

I have JS objects like these:

```
{
 name : "sldjfvbsdolbobgsd",
 myWeight : "[1,65,34,4,6,7,4,4,7,8,5]"
}
```

For each such object, there is a circle in an SVG element in force-directed layout.
'`i`' is a global variable. I am displaying the '`name`' element of each object like this currently:

```
node.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "nodetext")
                    .attr("dx", 12)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .text(function (d) { return d.name; });
```

I want to display both the name and the current weight of each object. I tried something like this but it didn't work:

```
*node.append("text")
                    .attr("class", "nodetext")
                    .attr("dx", 12)
                    .attr("dy", ".35em")
                    .html(function (d) { return d.name; } + "<br />" + function (d) { return d.myWeight[i]; });*
```

The output for every node is like this:

```
function (d) { return d.name; }function (d) { return d.myWeight[i]; }
```

whereas I want:

```
sldjfvbsdolbobgsd
34 // say, if `i` is 2
```

Please help me with displaying it correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code doesn't work is because d3 expects the argument passed to `.html` to be either a function or a constant. In your case the `+` causes the functions to be converted to strings. So the constant that you pass to `.html` ends up being:

```
function (d) { return d.name; } <br /> function (d) { return d.myWeight[i]; }
```

However, the SVG `text` element does not render the `<br/>` tag and so you don't get the line break.

The proper way to add line breaks inside SVG `text` is to use `tspan` with `dy` offets:

```
var text = node.append("text")
    .attr("class", "nodetext")
    .attr("dx", 12)
    .attr("dy", ".35em");

text.append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", 0)
    .attr("x",0)
    .text(function(d) {return d.name;});

text.append("tspan")
    .attr("dy", "1.2em") // offest by 1.2 em
    .attr("x",0)
    .text(function(d) {return d.myWeight;});
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked just fine!
Just one more thing - I'm trying to display only the ith element of d.myWeight, not the whole array. 'i' is a global variable and increments on click. But that change is not displayed in the label text even though I changed the function to return d.myWeight[i]. 

Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Oh, I get it. I need to set the tspan texts too on every click.